# DayPilot - Gridview not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, daypilot

I am using Daypilot Calendar.

The issue I have is that whenever there is a change, such as EventResize or EventMove on the calender the Gridview should update with the latest values

Example EventResize

```
 protected void DayPilotCalendar1_EventResize(object sender, EventResizeEventArgs e)
{
    int id = e.Recurrent ? Convert.ToInt32(e.RecurrentMasterId) : Convert.ToInt32(e.Id);
    new DataManager_MasterRota().MoveAssignment(id, e.NewStart, e.NewEnd, e.NewStart.DayOfWeek);
    DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager_MasterRota().GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar1);
    DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
    DayPilotCalendar1.Update();


    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The Gridview1.DataBind() is being hit when an event is resized but its not actually refreshing the data on the gridview. I have to hit F5 to refresh the page for it to actually take affect on the Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="94px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonId" HeaderText="PersonId" SortExpression="PersonId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="a" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="a" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Your gridview is in some panel?

Comment: I tried it both inside and without an update panel and the result is the same, it fails to refresh to update the gridview data

Comment: I actually changed the EventResize to a postback and it worked. Is it possible to work with Callback?

Comment: Yes, because the data within your grid is cached and not refreshed after update.

Comment: Can I get the Gridview to update using Callback rather that postback?

Comment: Put your gridview within updatepanel and within row_updated event, set GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133828/discussion-between-m-adeel-khalid-and-david-hayward).

Answer (score 0):

If the EventResizeHandling property is set to "CallBack" or "Notify" it uses ASP.NET CallBack mechanism to fire the server-side event. The ASP.NET CallBack runs in a simplified mode - the event handler can only change the component itself (DayPilotCalendar in this case).

If you want to change other controls on the page you need to switch to "PostBack" and place the controls in an UpdatePanel.